# Remove Black border around svgIcon <mat-icon>

Tags: html, css, svg, angular-material

I have a `search_icon` acting as a button in my HTML and it is working, but I cannot figure out how to remove the black box around the icon.  I have tried `outline: none;` and `border: none;`, but nothing seems to remove it.

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<button id="search-button" [disabled]="!(isOnline$ | async)" 
        (click)="onExpandFilter()"><mat-icon class="search-icon" svgIcon="search_icon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
```

Here is the css:

```
.search-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: let's c the parent code?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `box-shadow` property from the class `.search-icon`

```
.search-icon { width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 12px; border-radius: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the border is on the outer `button` element, not the SVG/icon. Based on your example:

```
<button id="search-button" [disabled]="!(isOnline$ | async)" 
    (click)="onExpandFilter()"><mat-icon class="search-icon" svgIcon="search_icon"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

I would suggest adding CSS for the button like:

```
#search-button {
    border: none;
}
```

or something similar.